# Installing jetty through puppet module

Tags: module, puppet, sudo, yum

I am new  to Puppet and want to install jetty, through the module that is already available here  [Link](http://forge.puppetlabs.com/maestrodev/jetty)

For this I installed the jetty module using this:

```
puppet module install maestrodev-jetty
```

Now I have this file structure

```
puppet
    == modules
       ==== jetty
    == manifests
       ==== site.pp
       ==== classes
              == gg_jetty.pp
```

the **gg_jetty.pp** has the following content :

```
class gg_jetty{
   include jetty

   jetty{
       version => "9.0.4.v20130625",
       home    => "/opt",
       user    => "jetty",
       group   => "jetty",
   }

}
```

the **site.pp** has the following content :

```
import classes/*.pp
node default{}
node 'pajetty1'{include gg_jetty}
```

Now when I run the command like this in **'pajetty1'** using :

```
puppet agent --no-daemonize --verbose --onetime
```

It shows me following error:

[image]

What I am doing wrong, (also for  viewing the pic please right click the image and open in new tab)

Thanks in advance..

Answer (score 2):

´jetty{´ needs a name:

```
class gg_jetty{
   include jetty

   jetty{'foo':
       version => "9.0.4.v20130625",
       home    => "/opt",
       user    => "jetty",
       group   => "jetty",
   }

}
```

So catalog load fails, and **puppet uses cached catalog**

By other side, it seem's that your version (9.0.4.v2013062 , **with last 5 missing**)   is not accesible through your yum repos. Type `yum info jetty` to see what versions have you available through `yum`, and change either repos or recipes to make them match.

Comment: What does this name means in real ?

Comment: Is the name of the resource. Then, you can use this name for ordering relationship, `Jetty['foo']->Exec['your script using jetty']`, and things like that.